# Double border CSS3 - FF !Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, css

I'm wondering, why this double border on table `TDs` won't show in Chrome but only in FF? Any ideas what could be the work around? Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/yQQLk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works in both the browsers:

```
td {
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px  0 #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px  0 #000;
        border-bottom: 1px solid red;
         box-shadow: 0 2px  0 #000;

}
```

I guess, this is the  problem:  `box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;`

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you're using `box-shadow` to produce a double border, when the `border` property itself already supports a double border on its own. Just use the following CSS instead of what you've got:

```
td {
    border-bottom: 3px double red;
}
```

Note you'll need to increase the size of the border to `3px` so that both of the lines show up (with `1px`, it sometimes doesn't show up at all when you specify `double`).

The other advantage is that this will work in all browsers, including older ones which don't support `box-shadow`.

Comment: well the reason I'm using box-shadow is because I would like to have a two color border one above the other one (no space in between), as it shows on the original fiddle. I'm not sure if it is possible to get the same result using `double`

Comment: hmm, maybe not; I think the `double` border is limited to a single colour... but I couldn't see the original fiddle the way you intended as I'm using Firefox 3.6, and the `box-shadow` didn't work for me. Sorry I missed the point though.

Answer (score 2):

Increase your border thickness to to see a more [obvious demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Hbtuh/3/) of the rendering differences between the two browsers. It seems that in FF, the box-shadow is overlaid on top of the border, in Chrome it hides underneath.

You could use another approach - perhaps use a border-bottom combined with a text-decoration: underline.